# hedging with known volatility

Tags: equities, hedging

Suppose we have a stock $X$ at which trades at 100 dollars. We suppose the stock follows a geometric brownian motion. We know that the interest rate is zero and annual volatility is 10 percent. How can we hedge the risk?

Comment: Delta hedging of a vanilla European option on X?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to hedge - an option? If yes- which one ?

Comment: Please tell us what your are asking.

Comment: There may be an option somewhere....

Answer (score 1):

You sell your stock $S$ against some cash.

Comment: correct answer ...

Answer (score 0):

You need a risk model to understand the sources of risk for your stock. If the risk factors can be traded then you can use the factor loadings to hedge your risk.

Comment: This is only true if the factor are investable. This is a geometric Brownian motion - this is theoretical only.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to define "hedge". Or else the question remains undefined, and the minimum risk is achieved not trading at all  ;-)